# Existence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a non empty subset of $\mathbb R$ having a limit point $L$. Show that there exists a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of distinct elements of $S$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n = L$.

Comment: What definition of limit point are you using?  Because in one definition, that statement is a given.

Answer (score 0):

For each positive integer $n$, consider the neighborhood (open ball) $$N_n = B_{\frac{1}{n}}(L)$$ centered at $L$ with radius $\frac{1}{n}$.  By the definition of a limit point, there is a point $u_n \in N_n \cap S$ such that $u_n \neq L$.  Now the sequence $\{ u_n \}$ converges to $L$.  I've left out that the $u_n$'s are distinct, but you can make a remark in the construction about how to choose them.